# How can I replace the comma-separated Id's with the names of services

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use different tables in my SQL report. I want to display in one of the columns the names of services.

I must have to take the names from an another table. How can I replace the comma separated Id's with the names of services?

Table 1

```
IdPerson   Date          Services 
------------------------------------                                           
12345      01 01 2019    1,5,15,17
```

Table 2

```
IdServices      description
----------------------------
 1              service 1
 2              service 2
 3              service 3
. . .
17              service 17
```

The expected output is like this:

```
ClientId    Date          Services 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       01 01 2019    service 1,service 5, service 15, service 17
```

Comment: Do not store lists of numbers as a comma-delimited list.  The correct way to represent such information in a relational database uses a junction/association table.

Comment: Which database ?

Comment: There are possible solutions but they depend on the RDBMS that are you using (oracle, postgres, sql-server, mysql, ...). Please **tag** your question properly.

Comment: I would start by reading about JOINS and GROUP BY in sql. Those should solve your problem.

Comment: it is a ms sql database

Comment: My usual question when I see data like this, is whether you have capacity to change the way the data is stored. Storing comma separated values in a single field is a REALLY poor design choice in a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem as follows:

---

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT Table_1.ClientId, Table_2.IdServices, Table_2.description
  FROM Table_1   AS Table_1
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Table_1.Services, ',') AS s
  INNER JOIN Table_2 AS Table_2
  ON s.value = Table_2.IdServices
)
SELECT 
Table_1.ClientId,
Table_1.Date,
Table_1services.services AS Services
FROM  
  Table_1 
  LEFT JOIN 
       (
             SELECT ClientId, STUFF((
             SELECT '; '+ description  FROM x AS x2 
             WHERE x2.ClientId = x.ClientId
             ORDER BY IdServices FOR XML PATH, 
             TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS "services"
             FROM x
             GROUP BY ClientId
       ) AS Table_1services ON Table_1.ClientId = Table_1services.ClientId
```

Comment: While your answer may be correct, it lacks explanation that describes "Why" it's correct. You should try to expand on your answers and not just provide code samples.

Comment: Additionally, you're using the `STRING_SPLIT()` function, which is only available in SQL2016 and above. You should probably mention this caveat in your answer.